# SvelteKit ssr not working on docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-3

I create svelteKit project with adapter-node for build production and run it with docker-compose. It works but the SSR not working, but when I try to run without docker with `yarn run build` and `node build` its works with SSR. maybe that my DockerFile setup wrong or there setup that i miss?

this `svelte.config.js`

```js
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: preprocess(),

    kit: {
        adapter: adapter(),

        // Override http methods in the Todo forms
        methodOverride: {
            allowed: ['PATCH', 'DELETE']
        }
    }
};

export default config;
```

this `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:16-alpine3.14

WORKDIR /home/node/app

ENV PORT=80

COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./

RUN corepack enable && \
    yarn install --frozen-lockfile

COPY . .
RUN yarn run build

EXPOSE ${PORT}/tcp

CMD ["node", "build"]
```

this `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  share:
    container_name: "cosmo-share"
    build: .
    ports:
      - 80:${PORT}
```

and this the `index.svelte` the page i called

```html
<script context="module" lang="ts">
    import { MetaTags } from 'svelte-meta-tags';

    export async function load(loader: any) {
        const { fetch, url } = loader;
        try {
            const id = url.searchParams.get('id');
            if (id != null) {
                const link = `${import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL}/api/v1/gallery/id?id=${id}`;
                const response = await fetch(link);
                if (response.ok) {
                    const data = await response.json();
                    return {
                        status: 200,
                        props: {
                            id: id,
                            image: data.data.path.path,
                            title: data.data.name
                        }
                    };
                } else {
                    return {
                        status: 200,
                        props: {
                            id: id,
                            image: '',
                            title: ''
                        }
                    };
                }
            } else {
                return {
                    status: 200,
                    props: {
                        id: id,
                        image: '',
                        title: ''
                    }
                };
            }
        } catch (err: any) {
            return {
                status: 200,
                props: {
                    id: '',
                    image: '',
                    title: ''
                }
            };
        }
    }
</script>

<script lang="ts">
    export let id: string;
    export let image: string;
    export let title: string;
</script>

<MetaTags
    title="Ubersnap - Cosmo share"
    titleTemplate="%s | Ubersnap - Cosmo"
    description="Ubersnap cosmo gallery"
    canonical="https://ubersn.app/"
    openGraph={{
        url: `https://ubersn.app?id=${id}`,
        title: 'Ubersnap - Cosmo gallery',
        description: 'Ubersnap cosmo gallery',
        images: [
            {
                url: image,
                alt: title
            }
        ],
        site_name: 'Ubersnap'
    }}
    twitter={{
        handle: '@handle',
        site: '@site',
        cardType: 'summary_large_image',
        title: 'Ubersnap - Cosmo share',
        description: 'Ubersnap cosmo gallery',
        image: image,
        imageAlt: title
    }}
/>
<div>
    {#if image}
        <img class="content-image" src={image} alt="original data" />
    {:else}
        <p style="color: red">{'There was error'}</p>
    {/if}
</div>

<style>
    .content-image {
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

The metadata its render but not with dynamic value. but when i build and run without docker its works.

I test with `yarn run build` and `node build` without docker and access the site with view-source:http://localhost:3000/?id=6283075c1d13e7342ce29ca8 i got the result with [image: Without Docker]

And test again with `docker-compose up` and access the size with view-source:http://localhost/?id=6283075c1d13e7342ce29ca8 i got the result with [image: With Docker]

the diff its same variable its missing that image link and the title of the image

## Update

so far i found that the promblem on docker-compose cause when i try to build image directly with `docker run` without docker-compose that works well. maybe something wrong with my docker-compose.yml

Comment: What's the error message, stacktrace, logs, etc?

Comment: there is no error message. so when I inspect the element it shows the dynamic value. but when I view-source: it just use blank it's like the image and title its undefined @MikkoOhtamaa

Comment: Can you add the relevant information how do you test and what is the result to the question

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Yeah i already update the question with the test and the result

Comment: It is suspicious that it works with plain docker but not docker-compose. Try removing `build .`, not sure if it needs to be run every time you up it.